# Importing sklearn from a local directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, ipython, package

I am using anaconda distribution over a server with no root access. In order to use sklearn latest version I installed it into my home directory [/hone/ram] and it is installed at `/home/ram/local/lib/python27/site-packages/`

Now I want to use this version of sklearn  instead of the default version installed at `/soft/anaconda/python2.7/lib/python2.7/`

I tried to modify sys.path variable by inserting `/home/ram/local/lib/python27/site-packages/` at 0 position in path variable  using `sys.path.append` function.

When I am doing this through my shell python interpretor python is able to load sklearn from my home directory i.e from  `/home/ram/local/lib/python27/site-packages/` but when I am doing this through ipython notebook this is not working.

Even after adding `/home/ram/local/lib/python27/site-packages/` to path variable in ipython notebook.  when I trys to import sklearn it still imports from the default path `/soft/anaconda/python2.7/lib/python2.7/`

What I am missing here ?

Comment: If you use `sys.path.append()`, it will add it to the *end* of sys.path, so import will look in the Anaconda directories first. If you want your directory to take precedence, put it first in sys.path using `sys.path.insert`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your custom folder appears before system ones in `sys.path`. I guess, you need to use [sys.path.insert(0, "/my/path")](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of `sys.path.append`

Comment: did that but still the problem exist

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is in `sys,path` 'cause I have almost a half of my python stuff  installed in the user directory (with `pip install --user...) and everything works just fine. Please demonstrate us `sys.path` as well as import errors. You may try to run an interactive python session, and perform these tests (setting the library path, import modules and so on) step by step interactively